# <?PHP getting changed into <!--?PHP

Tags: php

When I post a PHP code snippet into a wordpress post it will convert

`<?PHP` into `<!--?PHP`

To avoid this I must replace `<?PHP` with `&lt;?PHP`

I am asking if there is a setting or easy method to avoid this?  If not I am thinking of maybe writing a PHP function that will search the content filed and replace `<?PHP` with `&lt;?PHP`

Any ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my only idea so far

```
function strip_php($content) {
    return str_ireplace("<?PHP", "&lt;?PHP", $content  );
}
add_filter('content_save_pre','strip_php');
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP is filtered out of the WordPress post editor as a security feature. There are some plugins that let you put them in, but I think they're a pretty bad idea, so I won't even link to them.

If you need PHP on a page, you should be putting that code in a template file or in functions.php or a plugin file that hooks to a page you want to modify.

Comment: Hello sorry I wasn't clear, I am posting code for my syntax highlighter to show the code on the screen, not run the code.  I used to use a syntax plugin but now I am using my own.  Maybe my old syntax highlighter filtered this for me and I didn't realize it

Comment: Aha. I understand. I suspect you're right that this is getting filtered out. I like Syntax Highlighter Evolved from Automattic. (http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/syntaxhighlighter/)

Comment: That is the plugin I have always used but I just switch to the new Rainbow.js its more lightweight and better IMO http://craig.is/making/rainbows

Comment: If you take a look at Syntax Highlighter (http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/syntaxhighlighter/tags/3.1.2/syntaxhighlighter.php)  evolved you'll see that it's way more than just a JS highlighting library. I don't see why you'd want to reinvent the wheel on this one.

Comment: That plugin is simply a wrapper for Alex Gorbatchev JS highlighter, the only "other" stuff it does is detect which brush files to load and a few other minor things... It's a great library but it's a bit outdated and better JS highlighters are on the market now like Rainbow.js much better performace, also this new one Prism from Lea Verou.  I't not re-inventing the wheel its taking an old sluggish library and replacing with a new fast one